# timestretch/flextime in Ableton Live

Tags: time-stretching, ableton, logic

might be a lazy question but i'll give it a try anyway: what is the Logic Flex Time Editing equivalent in Ableton Live? is there any convenient built-in feature within Live for changing the duration of an audio fragment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equivalent to Flex in Logic is called Warping in Ableton Live.

When you load a sample in Ableton Live project it is automatically warped. This means that Ableton Live attempts to detect the correct tempo and creates "warp markers" that are shown in the sample (clip) view. Warp markers are placed usually on ones and rhythm transients. You can now easily add, delete and move these warp markers to get the timing of the parts right.

There are five different algorithms to do the time-stretching of a sample: Beats, Tones, Textures, Re-pitch and Complex. Each of these algorithms affect the sound in different manner. Usually Beats is good for drums, tones and textures work well for strings and human voices. Re-pitch creates a vinyl-like pitching effect on the sample when you move the warp markers. Complex works on any material, but is very CPU-intensive.

Anyway, the whole deal of getting timing parts right and doing time-stretching in Ableton Live is very easy and fun. And playing with those algorithms is extremely fun, you can easily find new and unexpected results. Hope this helps!

Comment: I don't think anyone could improve on this answer, a perfect description of Ableton's warping capabilities :)

Comment: the transient thing works in a similar way in both programs. however Flex in Logic lets you timestretch a sample's length by simply clicking & dragging it in the arrangement view - which i find very useful when syncing sound events to video. can you do that in Ableton as well? 

Comment: @kampana You can't actually stretch in the arrangement view in Ableton Live. When you select a clip on the timeline, you'll see it open up below the arrangement view. In this clip view you can access the warp markers and do the stretching. This clip view looks similar to the Sample Editor in Logic 8 but with some very cool features such as clip automation envelopes. Unfortunately there are no proper waveform editing capabilities in that view.